# Execution Error using out parameter in Oracle

Tags: oracle

```
begin
Num NUMBER;
EXEC GwInwForceQueueUpdateUser
('ITSC1','A07','167321','22202244333','20091103','1','110',:num);
end;
```

Error on line 0

```
begin
Num NUMBER;
EXEC GwInwForceQueueUpdateUser
('ITSC1','A07','167321','222

got Error : 
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMBER" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
     form
   current cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PL/SQL code should look like this:

```
declare
   Num NUMBER;
begin
   GwInwForceQueueUpdateUser('ITSC1','A07','167321','22202244333','20091103','1','110',num);
end;
```